# Matching Solar Panel to TP4056 Charge Controller

Tags: solar-cell, solar-charge-controller

I would like to match [solar panel](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32873990770.html) (6 V\1000 mA) to [charge controller](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4001196670805.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.3e4639f2MT8Ej4&algo_pvid=0e286070-3fc1-446f-9d8b-671e839618ed&algo_exp_id=0e286070-3fc1-446f-9d8b-671e839618ed-0&pdp_ext_f=%7B%22sku_id%22%3A%2210000015268548938%22%7D&pdp_pi=-1%3B2.13%3B-1%3B-1%40salePrice%3BAUD%3Bsearch-mainSearch) based `TP4056` in order to charge `18650 battery` around 3200 mAh.

In the TP4056 [datasheet](https://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Prototyping/TP4056.pdf) it says that the input voltage range is between `4 - 8 V`, but I saw in several places that the input should not get over 5 V (for example- [here](https://easyeda.com/Little_Arc/TP4056), and the module description in Aliexpress says 4.5 - 5.5 V).

1. Why is there different between the the two input voltage range?
2. According to 5 V input, if the solar panel voltage will get to lets say 7v on sunny day, or 6 V on MPP, will the TP4056 module will tolerate it?
3. According to 5 V input, if the solar panel voltage will get to 4 V on bit cloudy day, the TP4056 will stop charging?
4. Maybe that TP4056 does not supposed to work with solar panels (so their voltage vary)?

I don't know if the seller on Aliexpress does not provide the right description, or the data sheet are not accurate, or that I am missing something.

If someone have experience with that ill be happy for guidance.

**EDIT:**

This is the schematics for the TP4056 module:

[image]

Comment: Please post a manual or schematic for the charge controller otherwise this question is off topic

Comment: There may well be a difference between what the chip itself can accept and what their module based around the chip has been designed to accept.

Comment: Note that "Abs Max" ratings are not supposed to be used as normal operational ratings.

Comment: @VoltageSpike I wish I had schematics, they dont provide it on Aliexpress...

Comment: Well, the only other option would be to reverse engineer the schematic, because that's what would have to happen to answer the question.

Comment: I added the schematics, on datasheet the Vcc range is between 4v - 8v, and its also connected to CE, I didnt see voltage range about the CE..

Answer (score 3):

TP4056 is linear charging controller. That means it will dissipate power in order to regulate power that goes into battery. The higher input voltage and higher current the higher power is dissipated in TP4056 itself.
So, if the input voltage is 6V and charging current 1A, and battery is at say 4V, it would have to dissipate (6V-4V)*1A=2W. That is quite a lot for SO-8 package.
SO-8 has thermal resistance around 100 K/W, so I would not dissipate 2W in that. I would dissipate much less than 1W in that. Like 0.5 W, or so.

There is several options you could do:

- Use 5V panel instead of 6V
- Use 6V panel you have and add 1 or 2 silicon diodes in series. They will drop some voltage (and so offload TP4056) and they will act as reverse protection diodes as well
- Set it for lower current, like 500mA

You can even combine those options.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, it makes sense :)
what about the input range of the TP4056 module? the solar panel voltage vary and can go lower than 4.5v or higher than 5.5v (without the diodes for example)

Comment: When the voltage of solar panel goes under ~4.5V, the battery charging will stop.

Comment: TP4056 is built in thermal limitation. Not ideal, but it won't fry itself due to overheating.

Comment: @winny Yes, it has built in thermal limitation. I know that. It doesn't change my answer, because I would not design to dissipate 2W in SO-8 package.

Comment: Indeed. 5 V would be much easier.

Comment: im sorry, I didnt quite understand, the input voltage range of the charge controller is 4.5-5.5v? or 4-8v? how can you tell? (if its 4.5-5.5 its also inefficient, because the solar panel can produce 4v and the CC will not work. if he solar panel produce 6v its more than the CC can handle..)

Comment: @user1673206 You have to get datasheet for your part. Aliexpress is full of clones, and even TP4056 is largely cloned. I made about 3 orders of TP4056 on aliexpress and every time I received clone, every time a little bit different. Li-ion battery is 4.2V charged. So 4.0V is not enough to charge to 4.2V. The original datasheet says 4.0-6.0V

Comment: @Chupacabras I see. I don't expect much from Aliexpress.. do you familiar with manufactor that sells this module (with protection..)?

Comment: @user1673206 I'm not using modules. I'm using chips in my own boards/projects. I stopped to buy chips from aliexpress. I'm buying from distributors like lcsc, mouser, tme.

Comment: @Chupacabras ok thanks :)